# What is this method of recording hits in kyūdo called?

Tags: archery

I'm interested in learning about the symbols and what do they mean in the given below image. I tried searching online but I was not able to find this hit recording methodology of kyūdo.

I'm well aware of the possibility that this could be different for different people based on their preferences as it is a matter of recording your progress. But what I'm looking for is a standard system like in chess for recording your moves.

What is it called and how does it work? Where can one find more information on using it?

[image]